# Jquery - adding select option dynamically as html string from asp.net - Not Working

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am sending an ajax request to a web method in asp.net which returns a string containing html tags. The C# code is as follows -

```
string str="";
for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
   str += "<option value='2'>One</option>";
}
return str;
```

In query I am receiving this response data & I am adding this to a html select using jquery as below.

```
var optionsHtml = data.d.split(":");     
$('#ddlCartons").html(optionsHtml);
```

But this is giving an error directly from jquery.js file -

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]
```

But, instead of optionsHtml, if a hardcode string is given like -

```
$('#ddlCartons").html("<option value='2'>Hii</option><option value='2'>Hii</option><option value='2'>Hello</option>");
```

it is working fine.
So, what's wrong going on so that its giving error?

Comment: why you are splitting with ":"?

Answer (score 2):

What i can see is, problem is with split function you have used, what is the necessity of split you can directly append the string you have received from function.. Directly go for this:

```
$('#ddlCartons").html(data.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the split function you are creating an array `'optionsHtml'`.  This cannot be used to set the HTML property of `#ddlCartons`.

Use the `data.d` or `$('#ddlCartons").html(optionsHtml[0]);`